# How to interact with browser dowlnoads pop ups by using tosca

Tags: tosca

I am getting  the following error  when I try to click the "Save As" button in the downloads box. I have tried using an image scanner, but it isn't working.

The Algorithmic Association with name "Controls" is not supported by "Tricentis.Automation.Engines.Adapters.Controllers.DefaultContextAdapterController"

[image]

Need to handle the downloads pop up and click on save as option

Answer (score 0):

For me using keyboard shortcuts worked. ctrl + j to open downloads, tab to navigate to the buttons then return to select.